# How to calculate $\int_{S^1}\frac{1}{|w-z|^2}ds(w)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functions

$S^1$ is the unit circle on the complex plane,$ds$ is the normalized lebesgue measure on $S^1$, $z\in \mathbb{D}$ which is the open unit disk on the complex plane.

How to calculate $\int_{S^1}\frac{1}{|w-z|^2}ds(w)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie.I just do some change of variables. but those do not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is invariant with respect to rotation.

We can thus assume that, up to a rotation, $w$ lies on the real positive axis, with the unique condition $w \neq 1$.

The integral can be transformed, using $z=e^{it}$, giving $dz=ie^{it}dt=i(\cos(t)+i \sin(t))dt$ into:

$$i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\cos(t)+i \sin(t)}{(w-\cos(t))^2+(\sin(t))^2}dt$$

$$=i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\cos(t)+i \sin(t)}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt$$

$$=i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{\cos(t)}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt+i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{i \sin(t)}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt \ \ (1)$$

The second integral is zero because it is the integral of an odd function on a symmetric interval $[-a,a]$.

Let

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{-2w \cos(t)}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt$$

be a slightly modified version of the first integral.

**Edit**: Let us decompose the numerator of I into two parts (by introducing the denominator inside the numerator):

$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt-(1+w^2)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{1}{w^2+1-2w \cos (t)}dt$$

The first integral has value $2\pi$.

In the second integral, we recognize (up to a constant factor $(1-w^2)$) the Poisson Kernel $P_r(\theta)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel with its classical Fourier series decomposition:

$$\frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r \cos \theta + r^2}= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} r^{|n|} e^{i n\theta} $$

whose integration term by term is immediate.

Comment: I have added an "Edit" mentionning the connection of your issue with the Poisson Kernel, that I had completely overlooked at first and that the proposal by @zhw. as awaked back.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $z= re^{is}.$ The integral equals

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left | \frac{1}{e^{it}-re^{is}} \right | ^2\,dt  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left | \frac{1}{1-re^{i(s-t)}}\right |^2\,dt$$

Inside the absolute values, the last integrand can be expanded into a geometric series. Use that, orthogonality, and Parseval to finish.